# Make aggregation operation with hibernate and Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have a table in database with id and number of rows:

```
_________________________
|id | A | B | C | D | E |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

I need to filter this values by D and E rows as a method parameter and return a count grouping by A, B, C filtered or not in case parameters are empty. So, the result should be like this:

```
[a1,b1,c1,4]
[a1,b1,c2,3]
[a1,b2,c1,1]
[a1,b2,c2,3]
```

I need to make this implementation using Hibernate and Spring Data.

Comment: Then you should study Hibernate and Spring documentation and try to implement it. If you come across a specific problem while doing so you should ask a question about that here, but you should not expect people to do all the work for you.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS For me aggregation is specific problem. I do not see any easy solution for it. Thank you for your valuable answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've made is using plain SQL to aggregate information and using Spring Data projections to receive this information without Hibernate Entity.

More information about Projections:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections